# gulp. moving files in neighbors dir

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

The simplified structure of the project [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqGri.png). JavaScript files that lie in the **es6** directory must be moved to the neighbors directory **js**.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('build-js', function () {
    gulp.src('app/core/**/es6/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ["env"]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(???)); // need move to ../js
});
```

Please, help me, how to implement this in gulp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the babel pipe doesn't move the js files that are in the es6 folder or add any folders.  And that your gulpfile.js is at the root level of your "app" folder.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {

    // with gulpfile.js at root of "app" folder
  return gulp.src('core/**/es6/*.js')

    .pipe(rename(function (file) {

      console.log("file.dirname = " + file.dirname);
        // file.dirname = AdminTools\es6
        // file.dirname = Permissions\es6

        //  strip off the last folder 'es6'
      var temp = file.dirname.split(path.sep)[0];

      file.dirname = temp + "/js";
        // file.dirname = AdminTools\js
        // file.dirname = Permissions\js
   }))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('core'));
});
```

Comment: Thank, you helped me to solve my problem. I replaced the lines `var temp = file.dirname.split (path.sep)[0]; file.dirname = temp + "/js";` on `file.dirname = file.dirname.replace(/es6/g, 'js');` because the number of directories before the javascript of the file can be different.